# Using for loop with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a loop like the following:

```
x_list = df['Column1'].unique()
for x in x_list:
    y = df.query('Column1 == "x" and Column2 == "No"')
    y_count = y['Column1'].count()
    print ('Total number of {} is {}.' .format(x, y_count))
```

However, always the **y_count** results in **zero**!!

e.g.,
Total number of x1 is 0.
Total number of x2 is 0.
Total number of x3 is 0.
etc.

What would be the problem?

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: give a sample of your table

Comment: @adhg Column1: x1, x1, x2, x3, x3, x3, x4, x4, x5, x5, x5\ Column2: Yes, No, Yes, No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes, No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seldom use query, my guess is because "Column1 == 'x'" was understood as choosing rows which the Column1 is equal to a 'x' as a string, not the value of your x variable.

<s>Try this instead:</s>

```
x_list = df['Column1'].unique()
for x in x_list:
    y = df.query('Column1 == {} and Column2 == "No"'.format(x))
    y_count = y['Column1'].count()
    print ('Total number of {} is {}.' .format(x, y_count))
```

Or consider this

```
for x, sub_df in df[df['Column2']=='No'].groupby('Column1'):
    y_count = len(sub_df)
    print('Total number of {} is {}.' .format(x, y_count))
```

Comment: the 2nd code worked correctly. The 1st one did not.